# How to create a index for a string / varchar prefix?

Tags: mysql, database, database-indexes

I'd like to create a index to improve the performance on a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE name LIKE 'Chris%'
```

How can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query would benefit from an index on the `name` column:

```
alter table example add index name (name);
```

You could also just index a prefix of the `name` column if it is a long column:

```
alter table example add index name (name(50));
```

Note that the index will only help with trailing wildcards, not leading wildcards. For example, these columns will **not** benefit from the index:

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE name LIKE '%Chris%'
SELECT * FROM example WHERE name LIKE '%Stryczynski'
```